# Documentum, FileNet and Open Text Cloud Presence

Tags: document-management

Does anyone know which of the 3 products - Documentum, FileNet and Open Text offer cloud presence?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know about EMC and OpenText cloud offers, but I know about IBM.

IBM offer all major ECM products in cloud:

- IBM FileNet P8 Platform
- IBM Case Manager
- IBM Content Manager OnDemand
- IBM Content Navigator

look for details
http://www.ibm.com/marketplace/cloud/enterprise-content-management/us/en-us

or just call your ibm sales rep

Comment: And IBM DataCap as well.